# Include JavaScript in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to HTML and developing and login form. Please find below the code I used. I want to import my JavaScript code into HTML form.please help me.

**C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\forsiteSystem\thems\js\validation.js**

```
 function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["login"]["email"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("Email must be filled out");
  return false;
  }
}
```

**C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\forsiteSystem\thems\login.html**

```
<html>
        <head>
            <title>Login form</title>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <script src="js/validation.js">
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div>
                <form name="login" action="" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
                    Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
                    password: <input type="text" name="pass"><br>
                    <input type="submit"  id="Submit_button" >
                </form>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: In `login.html`, you're not closing the meta tag, is that normal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include your `js` file properly like this:

```
<script src="js/validation.js">
```

This code works for me.try

```
<html>
        <head>
            <title>Login form</title>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <script src="js/builder.js">
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div>
                <form name="login" action="" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
                    Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
                    password: <input type="text" name="pass"><br>
                    <input type="submit"  id="Submit_button" >
                </form>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Your js file will be on same directory under `js` file with this name `builder.js`.
Code in js file is :

```
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["login"]["email"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("Email must be filled out");
  return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: im verry sorry to say still it doesn't work for me .

Comment: what is your file hierarchy ?

Comment: C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\forsiteSystem\thems\js\validation.js
C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\forsiteSystem\thems\login.html

Comment: Did you use my `js` or your own ? and how you include js

Comment: your js.
i have included login.html
 <script src="js/validation.js">
            </script>

Comment: please post your code again in your question area.check the source page whether your `js` file is included in your `html` page or not ?

Comment: Your new code works for me.Try to check on different browser.Remove cache.

Answer (score 1):

This tag should work:

```
<script src="js/validation.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Script path should be.

```
<script src="js\validation.js"></script>
```

Comment: please check the path you used as src

Answer (score 0):

Js path shoulb be `js/validation.js`

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login form</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script src="js/validation.js" type="text/javascript">
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <form action=".\login.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
                Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
                password: <input type="text" name="pass"><br>
                <input type="submit"  id="Submit_button" >
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how you can add js correctly

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/validation.js"></script>
```